# Why flutter building many times?

Tags: flutter, dart

[code screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4srJG.jpg)

**When i hot restart app flutter building 3 times**

**This is output result**

```
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
Restarted application in 1,018ms.
I/flutter ( 4736): Built Count: 1
I/flutter ( 4736): Built Count: 2
I/flutter ( 4736): writing...
I/flutter ( 4736): writing...
I/flutter ( 4736): reading...:
I/flutter ( 4736): reading...:
I/flutter ( 4736): Built Count: 3
I/flutter ( 4736): writing...
I/flutter ( 4736): reading...:
```

Comment: Please share the build method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Constructor of a widget could be called multiple times based on how many places it was declared. As long as you have const constructor and the values passed remains unchanged, the build method won't get trigged multiple times for every initialisation.

Comment: thank you i added my code according to your advice so i changed someting and its work!